# Enqueuing Font Awesome with CDN Embed code into Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

**Ok want to make sure I'm doing this right!**  I think I've got this working but want to make sure.  FYI: this is a wordpress site.

I'm enqueuing Font Awesome the *new way they are doing it now* - they email you a CDN script code to embed.  I realize the correct way to add the script into WordPress is to Enqueue it in the functions.php file - so here's what I did... is this correct?  (it does work but that doesn't mean I have it completely right...)

```
//* For importing fontawesome
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_fa' );
function wp_fa() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'font_awesome', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/4b9e255a4a.js' ); 
}
```

** I noticed in other tutorials on this there is something else at the end after the .js file like null, all, true or something which I don't have, but it is still working.  Can someone confirm if I have this code correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you have done is correct.

The other values you speak of are

- dependencies (This could be something that requires jquery)
- version (Really handy for adding a version number on the end of the script you are enqueuing)
- Whether you would like the script loading in the footer or not

So you could have something like this -

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'font-awesome-custom', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/4b9e255a4a.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
```

I know font-awesome does not have a dependency of jQuery, it is just there as an example of it.

Comment: Appreciated!  Is the version # of the script something I'm coming up with  to just help myself keep track of it OR is it the _actual real_  script version?  How do you know if a script even has a version #?  Also like for your example of the dependency that would mean in this case:  the script is _dependent on_ jQuery?

Comment: Regarding the dependency, yes. This would mean that jQuery is loaded before the script you are enqueuing.

The version would look like something in your source "script.js?1.0.0" You could change this so the browser renders the latest version and not a cached version of your scripts.